# How to make an array generate its elements randomly

Tags: c

Basically I need to compare the execution time of the array sorting with a lot of elements(500k element more or less) so I want to know if there is a way to make the array come up with its own elements
https://onlinegdb.com/Hp6MkbCeM

```
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("Enter size of array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //Initialize array
    int arr[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    printf("The current array is:\n");

    double time_spent = 0.0;//starting clock
    clock_t begin = clock();
    int temp = 0;
    //Calculate length of array arr
    int length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    //Sort the array in ascending order
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < length; j++)
        {
           if(arr[i] > arr[j])
           {
               temp = arr[i];
               arr[i] = arr[j];
               arr[j] = temp;
           }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    //Displaying elements of array after sorting
    printf("Elements of array sorted in ascending order: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    clock_t end = clock();
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nThe elapsed time is %f seconds", time_spent);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you need to write a loop that calls `rand()` to assign each element.

Comment: ... or that reads them from a file, or from a device such as `/dev/random`.  If you want the same sequence of "random" numbers for each trial then `rand()` with a pre-chosen seed or reading from a pre-generated file of numbers is the way to go.

Comment: If you want random Orcish names to test, [I have just the thing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/269448); `orcish(string, sizeof string)`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounded like a simple entertainment so I implemented a program using the Ada programming language. This solution should provide hints for your solution in C++ while providing you the opportunity to discover how to implement your answer in C++.

I decided the output of a very large array would not be useful since it is hard to read and evaluate the differences between different initial data orders, so I only output the elapsed time required to sort the array each time it is filled with random values.

The Ada source code is:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;  use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Generic_Constrained_Array_Sort;
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;
with Ada.Calendar; use Ada.Calendar;

procedure Main is

   -- Define the range of data used in the array to be sorted
   -- This is also the index range for the array.

   type Data_Range is range 0 .. 500_000;

   -- Make an instance of the generic discrete random number
   -- generator to produce values in the range of Data_Range

   package Rand_Data is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (Data_Range);
   use Rand_Data;

   -- Define the array type to be sorted

   type Data_Array is array (Data_Range) of Data_Range;

   -- Make an instance of the generic constrained array sort procedure
   -- customized to sort instances of Data_Array

   procedure my_sort is new Ada.Containers.Generic_Constrained_Array_Sort
     (Index_Type => Data_Range, Element_Type => Data_Range,
      Array_Type => Data_Array);

   -- Define the random number generator seed

   Seed : Generator;

   -- Create a procedure to fill the array with random values in the range
   -- of Data_Range

   procedure fill_array (Arr : out Data_Array) is
   begin
      for I in Arr'Range loop
         Arr (I) := Random (Seed);
      end loop;
   end fill_array;

   -- Create a procedure to time the sorting of the array and output the
   -- elapsed time of the sort operation

   procedure Time_Sort (Arr : in out Data_Array) is
      T1 : Time := Clock;
      T2 : Time;
   begin
      my_sort (Arr);
      T2 := Clock;
      Put_Line ("Sort time:" & Duration'Image (T2 - T1) & " seconds.");
   end Time_Sort;

   -- Create an instance of type Data_Array

   The_Array : Data_Array;

begin

   -- Set the random number seed based upon the value of the system clock

   Reset (Seed);

   -- Fill and sort the array 20 times

   for I in 1 .. 20 loop
      fill_array (The_Array);
      Time_Sort (The_Array);
   end loop;

end Main;
```

The output from a sample execution of the program is:

```
Sort time: 0.133331800 seconds.
Sort time: 0.133276200 seconds.
Sort time: 0.139969700 seconds.
Sort time: 0.132815500 seconds.
Sort time: 0.134336500 seconds.
Sort time: 0.135018800 seconds.
Sort time: 0.132183200 seconds.
Sort time: 0.134873900 seconds.
Sort time: 0.135876900 seconds.
Sort time: 0.136931200 seconds.
Sort time: 0.134980000 seconds.
Sort time: 0.137260000 seconds.
Sort time: 0.132401800 seconds.
Sort time: 0.137554000 seconds.
Sort time: 0.133554800 seconds.
Sort time: 0.134009500 seconds.
Sort time: 0.132895800 seconds.
Sort time: 0.134184000 seconds.
Sort time: 0.130988900 seconds.
Sort time: 0.132368300 seconds.
```